# IPFS Android Cant add file

Tags: ipfs, android, java

I am using the java-ipfs-api - https://www.npmjs.com/package/geth-private for my android DApp. I have managed to connect to the ipfs daemon and have tested it using the ipfs.refs.local(); command as stated on the github. However, when I try to add a file with

NamedStreamable.ByteArrayWrapper ipfsFile = new NamedStreamable.ByteArrayWrapper(usr + ".txt", userJSON.toString().getBytes());

MerkleNode addFile = ipfs.add(ipfsFile);

or even  with

NamedStreamable.FileWrapper file = new NamedStreamable.FileWrapper(new File("hello.txt"));
MerkleNode addResult = ipfs.add(file);

as given on the github page it just used the Adnroid Looper class and loops indefinitely and crashes. Can't find anything on the github about this or in the code. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

-- EDIT

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp, PID: 24710
                                                                                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/nio/file/Paths;
                                                                                      at io.ipfs.api.IPFS.add(IPFS.java:85)
                                                                                      at io.ipfs.api.IPFS.add(IPFS.java:70)
                                                                                      at benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:91)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.nio.file.Paths" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp-2/lib/x86, /data/app/benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                      at io.ipfs.api.IPFS.add(IPFS.java:85) 
                                                                                      at io.ipfs.api.IPFS.add(IPFS.java:70) 
                                                                                      at benkrarup.ethereum.messagingdapp.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:91) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

It's getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is late but I did create an implementation of IPFS that works with android. It is because java.nio.Paths is not available at API level 24.

-- I have posted a link on the github for the available code however it is a quick untested fix.

Comment: Can you share a link to your fix here, so it can help others?